# Pretty Url in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I use a [plugin](https://docs.yithemes.com/yith-woocommerce-ajax-product-filter/) to filter the WooCommerce products by categories. I would like to change the url that is generated during the filtering to pretty url.

So instead of `https://example.de/products/cars/?yith_wcan=1&product_cat=red`,
i would like to have `https://example.de/products/cars/red/`

The plugin doesn't support this by default, so I'm looking at add_rewrite_rule.

```
add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule', 10, 0);

function myplugin_rewrite_tag_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%cars%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_rule('cars/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=cars/?yith_wcan=1&product_cat=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

But the url /cars/ with the filter doesnt come up.

`echo add_query_arg( $wp->query_vars, home_url() );`

shows, that are non redirect url working.

I flash the permalinks, but it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not working because you haven't registered your query var.
Try this code.

```
function register_custom_query_vars($vars) {
  $vars[] = "cars";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'register_custom_query_vars');

function custom_rewrite_endpoint(){
  add_rewrite_endpoint( 'cars', EP_ROOT | EP_PERMALINK | EP_CATEGORIES | EP_PAGES );
}
add_filter('init','custom_rewrite_endpoint');

/**
* uncomment this for 
* flushing rewrite rules after changes 
**/
//flush_rewrite_rules(true);
```

https://example.de/products/cars/red/

```
<?php echo get_query_var('cars'); ?>
```

should output 'red'.

However, your woocommerce plugin might still need the initial $_GET query variables to work properly.
You could set the var – but it's not recommended:

```
$_GET['product_cat'] = $cars;
```

I you are already paying for this plugin, better insist on a proper integrated rewrite feature.